# How to Make Transformation Rule in Instant Article?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-instant-articles

Since i am using A div like:`<div class="rasi-wrap">`

so how what would be its transformation ? can anyone help me?

I tried:

```
{
  "rules":
   [
     {
       "class" : "InteractiveRule",
       "selector" : "div.rasi-wrap"
      }
]
```

but Nothings Happens and error remains same

Comment: Can you please try to upload your proper code or some more information about your error?

Comment: "No rules defined for <div class="rasi-wrap"> in the context of InstantArticle" this is the error

Comment: Write your rules according to this example: https://github.com/Automattic/facebook-instant-articles-wp/issues/473

Comment: i follow that steps but i didnt find the solution can you please help me out?

Comment: Do you have any outer tag of div?

Comment: <div class="rasi-wrap">
<div class="rasi-icon"><img class...
this is the html in my post content

Comment: Did you try  "selector" : "//[div.rasi-wrap]"

Comment: what would be in class?

Comment: nothings happens

Comment: Is Xpath Selector not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   { "rules":[{
      "class": "PassThroughRule",
      "selector" : "div.rasi-wrap"
    },
    {
    "class": "PassThroughRule",
      "selector" : "div.rasi-icon"
    }
]}
```

This is the correct answer i just chnaged the code given by Sweta Parmar and its the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write rules using different selectors:

```
{
  "class": "InteractiveRule",
  "selector" : "div.rasi-wrap" // CSS Selector
}
```

or

```
{
  "class": "InteractiveRule",
  "selector" : "//div[class=rasi-wrap]" // Xpath Selector
}
```

Comment: now error came:
**'Invalid selector for fields (interactive.iframe). The node being transformed was <div> in the context of InstantArticle within the Rule InteractiveRule with these properties: {}**